# Add "-" to varchar value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, varchar

I have a `TELEPHONE_NUMBER` as a `varchar` like this:

```
Value : "1112223344"
```

And I need to add "-" to the value like this:

```
111-222-33-44
```

So how can I add `-` to my telephone number value in my SQL Server stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TELEPHONE_NUMBER
   (@TELEPHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DOSYA_ARSIV(TELEPHONE_NUMBER)
   VALUES(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER)
END
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to store it as string and provide the formatting on the UI?

Comment: yes, leave formatting to the front end application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an alternative:

```
select SUBSTRING('1112223344',1,3)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING('1112223344',4,3)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING('1112223344',7,2)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING('1112223344',9,2)
```

In your case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TELEPHONE_NUMBER
   (@TELEPHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DOSYA_ARSIV(TELEPHONE_NUMBER)
   VALUES
   (
       SUBSTRING(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER,1,3)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER,4,3)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER,7,2)+'-'+
       SUBSTRING(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER,9,2)
   )
END
```

As noobob has mentioned in his comment, you may have this as an INT type (INT,BIGINT or something similar) and just handle the way it is displayed in the front end. For instance in C# you would have it as:

```
TELEPHONE_NUMBER.ToString("###-###-##-##");
```

Another comment would be that defining the expected argument as `VARCHAR(4000)` is way too much. Though it might not be very bad, it is a good point to define arguments or variables as close to expected input as you can. In your case i would say that something like `VARCHAR(30)` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function in the MS SQL server

```
SET @TELEPHONE_NUMBER=STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@TELEPHONE_NUMBER,4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),11,0,'-')
```

Comment: One thing i can see wrong here is that if the input is shorter than the expected, this produces a `NULL` value.